# Trying to create an animated radar chart in python plot.ly

Tags: python, animation, plotly, radar-chart

I'm trying to create radar charts in plotly exactly like the ones described [here](https://plot.ly/python/radar-chart/#basic-radar-chart)
Except I would like to animate the chart as it moves between different source data with a button. I've been trying to implement the animation mechanics described [here](https://plot.ly/python/animations/#offline-mode)

All of the examples of animations that I can find for plotly are only for cartesian coordinates. My code can initialize the radar chart but can't seem to get the animation to begin.

(run on Jupyter for the visualize to generate!)

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
from IPython.display import display, HTML

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

figure = {'data': [{'fill': 'toself',
          'r': [10, 7, 4, 3, 1, 10],
          'theta': ['A','B','C', 'D','E','A'],
          'type': 'scatterpolar',
          'mode': 'markers'}],

      'layout': {'title': 'radar Animation',
           'polar': {'radialaxis': {'range': [0, 10], 'visible': True}},
           'showlegend': False,
           'title': 'Start Title',
                 'updatemenus': [{'type': 'buttons',
                                  'buttons': [{'label': 'Play',
                                               'method': 'animate',
                                               'args': [None]}]}]},

      'frames': [{
        'data': [{'fill': 'toself',
                  'r': [2, 5, 10, 5, 2, 2],
                  'theta': ['A','B','C', 'D','E','A'],
                  'type': 'scatterpolar',
                  'mode': 'markers'}],

        'data': [{'fill': 'toself',
                  'r': [10, 7, 4, 3, 1, 10],
                  'theta': ['A','B','C', 'D','E','A'],
                  'type': 'scatterpolar',
                  'mode': 'markers'}],

        'layout': {'title': 'End Title'}

    },
                  ]}

 iplot(figure)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `scatterpolar` trace type doesn't currently support animation.

I confirmed this by searching for the `animatable` property in the plotly.js repository (https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=animatable&type=). At present, only the `scatter` and `carpet` trace types support animation.

Feel free to open a feature request issue in the plotly.js repository!

Comment: ok, thank you very much for helping me to verify this. I was worried that it wouldn't be possible but wasn't sure how to check.
I have decided to use Chart.js instead.